# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am coming to the error in Angular 4. (Angular-CLI), that says: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. So, I am new to Angular 4 coming from Angular 1. So, I will be thankful for your help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- using semantic-ui --> 
<form class="ui large form segment">
  <h3 class="ui header">Add a link</h3>
  <!-- added the title -->

  <div class="field">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input name="title" #newtitle>
  </div>
  <!-- added the link -->
  <div class="field">
    <label for="link">Link:</label>
    <input name="link" #newLink>
  </div>
  <!--added the button -->

  <button (click)="addArticle(newTitle, newLink)" class="ui positive right floated button">
    Submit Link
  </button>

</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link: HTMLInputElement):
    boolean {
    console.log(`Adding article title: ${title.value} 
    and link: ${link.value}`);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You casing of the reference variable and the parameter passed do not match. Change `<input name="title" #newtitle>` to `<input name="title" #newTitle>` since your are calling `addArticle` with `newTitle` with a capital T.